# IBM Worklight Adapter java

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I'm creating an adapter in java, and i wonder if it is possible to return the object ProductVO  to the adapter js, or first i need to convert the object to JSON String and return?

ProductAdapter-impl.js

```
 function getProductByBarCode(barCode){
    var productTest = new com.ciss.mobile.cissmarttax.service.ProductTest();
    return {
        result: productTest.getProductByBarCode(barCode,0)
    };
}
```

ProductTest.java

```
package com.ciss.mobile.cissmarttax.service;

public class ProductTest {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ProductTest.class.getName());

    public ProductVO getProductByBarCode(String barcode, Integer offset){
        //logger.info("getProductByBarCode invoked");           
        ProductFacade productFacade = new ProductImpl();
        try {
            List<ProductVO> products = productFacade.getProductByBarCode(barcode);

            if(products != null)
                return (ProductVO) products.get(0);         

        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a Java object. Well, technically it will be a reference to the Java object. You will be able to invoke instance methods.